# No rows selected sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to another user and then do a select, but I get "no rows selected" in output.

```
SHOW USER;
CONNECT USER1/USER1
SHOW USER;
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

Output:

USER is "SYS"
Connected
USER IS "USER1"
no rows selected
```

So I don't know why is not this working, can you help me?

Comment: is it possible that TABLE1 has Zero rows to be selected?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no

Comment: Let's see a script where you create a table, insert a row, and then select it back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `INSERT` data in one session and then log in (creating another session) and try to view the data then you will not be able to see it unless a `COMMIT` has been issued in the first session instructing the database to store the data and make it publicly visible. While data is uncommitted then it is only visible within the session within which it was  inserted (even if you log in as the same user).

To solve it:

- Go back to the first session and run a `COMMIT` statement.
- Then check if there are rows visible in the second session.

Comment: this is also my best guess

Comment: @MT0 No, I don't do any insert, I just do a connect then a select...